Convert a string with hex UTF codes to characters using busybox
I have a string with a file path, where non-ASCII characters are HEX-encoded.
For instance:
/media/\x444\x430\x439\x43b.txt

and I need to convert it to /media/файл.txt using busybox.
I can do this task using ruby:
n = '/media/\x444\x430\x439\x43b.txt'
n.gsub(/\\x\h{3}/){|h| [h[2..-1].to_i(16)].pack('U') }

How to perform this on busybox (version 1.19.4)?

Having hex with three characters is quite unusual. Common representations use bytes \x22\x33 or Unicode escapes \u0444\u0430.

Pure Busybox is probably not very well-equipped for this. Could you encode the characters into UTF-8 before turning them into hex? Then the byte-by-byte representation should be recoverable using e.g. Awk. (I suppose you could implement UTF-8 serialization in Awk, too; but that seems brittle and painful.)

How did you got that string? What tool uses triple chars with hex for escaping unicode characters? There is no common tool for that, write your own, parse the string char by char, handle escaping, conversion, outputting. It could be done in sh or awk. While ruby code is great- what have you tried in sh? And if you have that ruby, that you know, why not use it?

@KamilCuk: those file names came from the configuration files on embedded device for which I'm writing a shell script.  Unfortunately, I'm unable to install any space-consuming tools like ruby there.  I can't change the way the software stores that data.

Then you have to write a shell script that does that. So for each character in the string, if the character is not a /, output it, if it is a /, read the next 3 characters, convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8, and output the bytes. I think it has to be done in awk. What can you install? Perl or python?

What do these codes represent? UTF code points? Or some UTF encoding?

As a side note: Your Ruby program relies on doing a to_i based on a string holding a hex value. Plain Posix shell does not have this built in. Since it does have integer arithmetice, you should be able to write a parser for this and then perhaps (haven't tried) use printf and/or dd to squeeze the resulting value together.

Just an idea: Maybe the language bc could do the trick. I just noticed that it can be found on busy box, and it can do hex conversion.

@KamilCuk Unfortunately, I'm unable to install any space-consuming software like Perl or Ruby into that device.

Then, try to write it in busybox awk. I think everything is there in awk. And yes, you will have to write a parser and utf-16 to utf-8 algorithms - these are not trivial to write. Here https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html is a good awk introduction.


How to perform this on busybox (version 1.19.4)?

Redirect the input to awk. Set field separator to nothing.
In awk write a loop to iterate from 1 to NF, for every char, extract the i-th character from input.
If the i-th character is not a /, printf it.
Manage state of the parser. If the i-th character is a /, remember it in a variable. The next 3 characters are decimals, which have to be converted from string into a number and accumulated in another variable.
After converting the 3 characters to decimals, you'll get a UTF-16 characters. Now you have to write a function to convert UTF-16 to UTF-8. After conversion, output the utf-8 characters.
